# How do I split a string into substrings using a multi-character delimeter in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

It's obviously trivially easy to split a string into substrings delimited by a single character using split-sequence:split-sequence. It seems to me that it should be similarly easy to split a string into substrings delimited by a multi-character string. I'm writing a function to do this (having not found built-in/library), but am realizing that perhaps I'm missing something and wonder if you have pointers.

An examples of what I'm trying to do:

```
(special-split-sequence ". " "Hello. Dolly") ; -> ("Hello" "Dolly")
(special-split-sequence "xyz" "abcxyzabc") ; -> ("abc" "abc")
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you think it's any less trivial?

Comment: See [`split`](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str?tab=readme-ov-file#split-separator-s-key-omit-nulls-limit-start-end-regex) in the `str` library.

Comment: `cl-ppcre` has a [`split`](https://edicl.github.io/cl-ppcre/#split) function too that uses regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cl-ppcre`, or [the `str` library](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str/#split-separator-s-key-omit-nulls-limit-start-end-regex) whith `str:split` that does just that.

```lisp
(str:split ". " "Hello. Dolly") ;; -> ("Hello" "Dolly")
(str:split "xyz" "abcxyzabc") ;; -> ("abc" "abc")
```

It uses `cl-ppcre` under the hood, but it takes care of *not* treating the separator string as a regex by default. It is implemented like this:

```lisp
(defun split (separator s &key (omit-nulls *omit-nulls*) limit (start 0) end regex)
  "Split s into substring by separator (cl-ppcre takes a regex, we do not).

   `limit' limits the number of elements returned (i.e. the string is
   split at most `limit' - 1 times).
   If `regex' is not nil, `separator' is treated as a regular expression.

   Examples:
   (str:split \",\" \"foo,bar\") ;; => (\"foo\" \"bar\")
   (str:split \"[,|;]\" \"foo,bar;baz\" :regex t) ;; => (\"foo\" \"bar\" \"baz\")
"
  ;; cl-ppcre:split doesn't return a null string if the separator appears at the end of s.
  (let* ((limit (or limit (1+ (length s))))
         (res (if regex
                  (ppcre:split separator s :limit limit :start start :end end)
                  (ppcre:split `(:sequence ,(string separator)) s :limit limit :start start :end end))))
    (if omit-nulls
        (remove-if (lambda (it) (emptyp it)) res)
        res)))
```

Its other key arguments are `:omit-nulls`, `:limit`, `:start`, `:end`, `:regex`.

You had a hint on the Cookbook: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html

*(I am the original author of this lib)*

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer says you almost certainly want to use a preexisting library for this.  But, if you're feeling your oats and/or just enjoy writing things, or have specific requirements it's pretty easy to write one.  You also get the benefit that this will work on any sequence type, *but* in real life you would certainly wish the implementation to have a special case for lists as the complexity will be horrible there otherwise.

Rather than using `loop`, this version uses [a collecting macro](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#collecting-lists-forwards-and-accumulating-collecting), but here is an implementation of it (this is different to the actual implementation nowadays):

```
(defmacro collecting (&body forms)
  (let ((cvn (make-symbol "CV"))
         (ctn (make-symbol "CT")))
    `(let (,cvn ,ctn)
       (flet ((collect (it)
                (if ,cvn
                    (setf (cdr ,ctn) (list it)
                          ,ctn (cdr ,ctn))
                  (setf ,ctn (list it)
                        ,cvn ,ctn))
                it))
         (declare (inline collect))
         ,@forms
         ,cvn))))
```

And now:

```
(defun split-on-med (med sequence &key (start 0) (end (length sequence))
                         (test #'eql) (key #'identity))
  ;; There are lots of decisions about what should be the right answer
  ;; in edge cases which this makes but does not document.
  (declare (type sequence med sequence)
           (type (integer 0) start end)
           (type function test key))
  (let ((ml (length med)))
    (collecting
      (if (zerop ml)
          (do ((p start
                  (let ((n (1+ p)))
                    (collect (subseq sequence p n))
                    n)))
               ((>= p end)))
        (do ((p start
                (cond
                 ((< p end)
                  (let ((where (search med sequence :start2 p :test test :key key)))
                    (cond
                     (where
                      (collect (subseq sequence p where))
                      (+ where ml))
                     (t
                      (collect (subseq sequence p end))
                      (return)))))
                 ((= p end)
                  (collect (subseq sequence p end))))))
            ((>= p end)))))))
```

Now

```
> (split-on-med "xy" "axyzx")
("a" "zx")

> (split-on-med "" "xy")
("x" "y")

> (split-on-med #(1 2) #(1 2 3 4 1 2 5))
(#() #(3 4) #(5))

> (split-on-med #("a" "b") #("z" "q" "a" "b" "c") :test #'string=)
(#("z" "q") #("c"))
```

Comment: Should `split-on-mcd` be `split-on-med`?

Comment: @Shawn: yes, thank you (I renamed the function, the old one was still in the image).